# pdfkit on rails hangs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdfkit

I have a weird problem after I moved my rails application from shared hosting to VPS on DreamHost.
pdfkit hangs.

Page A is called and it generates a pdf from HTML(Page B).
But when Page A calls Page B, as Page A is not finished, Page B is waiting.
So this is basically circular problem.

This didn't happen before.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to have more than one rails process running, one to handle each request. Guessing your previous provider was running multiple processes?